# openshift: is it possible to create multiple mysql cartridges?

Tags: mysql, environment-variables, openshift

Openshift offers scalability. However, it seems to me, if you are using MySql, in the end MySql queries/hits will be the bottleneck (if you are lucky enough to generate traffic which need scalability and considering the max-connections limit on openshift).

Suppose I want to use OpenShift, is it possible to create multiple mysql cartridges to balance the load and create dynamic environmental variables to assign requests to different mySql cartridges? (suppose I send an id or something and the environment variable for the mysql is set to "dbname+lastdigit" of this id").

This is a simplified example which should multiply the database capacity by ten (if this is unrelated data). Can it be done?

I hope some openshift guy or girl will clarify this for me....

cheers

Edit: Thanks mbaird for your info:

To clarify: 
 I wasn't talking about auto-scaling but using for instance 11 static/persistant db-cartridges which would never scale up or down.

Then you could store user information in any of them depending on (also for instance) their last id-digit. 
 The 11th database cartride could be used as a table to get the user's id and then redirect that user to the right database (if last digit = 0, db = db0, if last digit = 1, db = db1 etc). This would enable me to call the right database for the right user.

Of course, this is not auto-scaling but it would multiply the database capacity by (roughly) ten.

However, this would require the ability to create multiple mysql cartridges and corresponding environmental variables to gain access to all these mysql cartridges.

It seems to me this not possible right now, so I will investigate your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenShift database tier currently doesn't scale. Further, even if you could add a second MySQL cartridge it wouldn't give you a scalable database, it would give you a new, empty database. What you are looking for is the ability to scale the MySQL cartridge across multiple gears, not adding another cartridge.

I've actually seen some comments from OpenShift (although I can't seem to find them now) that the databases on OpenShift are for development only and you should look for another service to host your database if you have a mission-critical application that requires database fail-over and scalability.

Since you are specifically using MySQL, I would look into using Amazon RDS (either MySQL or the new Aurora engine which is MySQL compatible) or ScaleDB.

Comment: You can also check out the OpenShift Marketplace (https://marketplace.openshift.com) to find database hosting options that offer scaling etc, here is the MySQL one: https://marketplace.openshift.com/apps/5798